# Upload a file on form submit using ASP.NET Web API (not Core) and Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I want to upload a file on form submit, its not posting on Web API.

I tried many solutions but in vain. I am now trying to get the file name but 505 errors still appear.

```
POST http://localhost:50700/api/User/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here my Angular code

```
handleFileInput(file:FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = file.item(0);
}

onRegister() {
    ...
    const user = new User(stuff)

    this._usersService.addUser(user,this.fileToUpload)//user
            .then((res) => {//code})
}
```

Service

```
addUser(user: User, form: File) {   
    var data = {user: user, image: form};
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.api,data,this.config).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          resolve(response);
          console.log(response);
        },
        (error) => {
          reject(error);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

ASP.NET Web API:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] UploadUserFile data)
{
    /*
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    */

    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    return Request.CreateResponse(data.image.FileName);
}
```

Class :

```
public class UploadUserFile
{
    public User user { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase image { get; set; }
}
```

Error :
ExceptionMessage:

> The object reference is not set to an instance of an object."
> ExceptionType: "System.NullReferenceException" Message: "An error has
> occurred.

## StackTrace :

> "   à prjBack.Controllers.UserController.Post(UploadUserFile data)
> dans
> C:\Users\technologi\Desktop\projet-aspmvc\prjBack\prjBack\Controllers\UserController.cs:ligne
> 47    à lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    à
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.b__2(Object
> instance, Object[] methodParameters)    à
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
> instance, Object[] arguments)    à
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
> controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---    à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    à
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---    à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    à
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()
> --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---    à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    à
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    à System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.

d__15.MoveNext()"

Comment: 500 error - check the log, what's the actual error? The details.

Comment: hi bro ,
ExceptionMessage: "La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet."
ExceptionType: "System.NullReferenceException"
Message: "Une erreur s’est produite."